# Perl: string formatting in tab delimited file

Tags: perl, matrix

I have no background in programming whatsoever, so I would appreciate it if you would explain how and why any code you recommend should be written the way it is.

I have a data matrix 2,000+ samples, and need to do the following manipulate the format in one column.

I would also like to manipulate the format of one of the columns so that it is easier to merge with my other matrix. For example, one column is known as sample number (column #16). The format is currently similar to `ABCD-A1-A0SD-01A-11D-A10Y-09`, yet I would like to change it to be formatted to the following `ABCD-A1-A0SD-01A`. This will allow me to have it in the right format so that I can merge it with another matrix. I seem to not be able to find any information on how to proceed with this step.

The sample input should look like this:

```
ABCD-A1-A0SD-01A-11D-A10Y-09
ABCD-A1-A0SD-01A-11D-A10Y-09
ABCD-A1-A0SE-01A-11D-A10Y-09
ABCD-A1-A0SE-01A-11D-A10Y-09
ABCD-A1-A0SF-01A-11D-A10Y-09
ABCD-A1-A0SH-01A-11D-A10Y-09
ABCD-A1-A0SI-01A-11D-A10Y-09
```

I want the last three extensions removed.  The output sample should look like this:

```
ABCD-A1-A0SD-01A
ABCD-A1-A0SD-01A
ABCD-A1-A0SE-01A
ABCD-A1-A0SE-01A
ABCD-A1-A0SF-01A
ABCD-A1-A0SH-01A
ABCD-A1-A0SI-01A
```

Finally, the matrix that I want to merge with has a different layout, in other words the number of columns and rows are different. This is a issue when I tackle the next step which is merging the two matrices together. The original matrix has about 52 columns and 2,000+ rows, whereas the merging matrix only has 15 column and 467 rows.

Each row of the original matrix has mutational information for a patient. This means that the same patient with the same ID might appear many times. The second matrix contains the patient information, so no patients are repeated in that matrix. When merging the matrix, I want to make sure that every patient mutation (each row) is matched with its corresponding information from the merging matrix.

My sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'sorted_samples_2.txt';

open(INFILE, $file) or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
open(my $outfile, '>', 'sorted_samples_changed.txt');

foreach my $line (<INFILE>) {
    print "The input line is $line\n";
    my @columns = split('\t', $line);

    ($columns[15]) = $columns[15]=~/:((\w\w\w\w-\w\d-\w|\w\w-\d\d\w)+)$/;

    printf  $outfile "@columns/n";
}
```

Issues: The code deletes the header and deleted the string in column 16.

Comment: The 'my' keyword before @sort should be one line higher, in the first line. And the word 'sort' is already used in Perl, so I'd find some other name for your array.

Comment: If you are a newbie - don't go near `map` - it'll burn you. Seriously. Try a `foreach` loop instead.

Comment: Please create sample perl project with few sample data at http://ideone.com/.

Comment: Grab a book, newbie. http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Perl.productCd-1118013840.html

Comment: Post up some sample input and clearly state what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Split task in peaces. with generating intermediate data so u can control that things goes right. in general MAP is advanced perl technique and I don't recommend it to you use it unless you clearly understand how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the capitalist way that, as a biologist who needs some programming work done, you should pay a programmer to do it, and asking for it to be done for no fee is rather cheeky. It makes it no better that your question asks for three specific things as if you were picking from a menu. That isn't a question, it's a contract. I wonder how you would take it if I posted a question asking for an hour or two's biology work to be done? If you want to employ someone then several of us, including myself, would be happy to do it for you.

Comment: @fugu: The `@ array` isn't a problem. Perl is fine with that. The biggest problem is that the OP hasn't copied the code properly, nor has he shown the code that produces the error that he quotes. As it stands it simply won't compile because almost all of the variables are undeclared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues about your code:

- Good job on include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).  Keep doing that
- Anytime you're doing file or directory processing, include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) as well.
- Always use lexical file handles `$infh` instead of globs `INFILE`.
- Use the 3 parameter form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).
- Always process a file line by line using a [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) loop.  Using a [`for`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/for.html) loop loads the entire file into memory
- Don't forget to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input from a file.
- Use the line number variable `$.` if you want special logic for your header
- The first parameter of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a pattern.  Use `/\t/`.  The only exception to this is `' '` which has special meaning.  Currently your introducing a bug by using a single quoted string.
- When altering a value with a regex, try to focus on what you DO want instead of what you DON'T.  In this case it looks like you want 4 groups separated by dashes, and then truncate the rest.  Focus on matching those groups.
- Don't use [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) when you mean [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).

The following applies these fixes to your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $infile = 'sorted_samples_2.txt';
my $outfile = 'sorted_samples_changed.txt';

open my $infh, '<', $infile;
open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    chomp $line;

    my @columns = split /\t/, $line;

    if ($. > 1) {
        $columns[15] =~ s/^(\w{4}-\w\d-\w{4}-\w{3}).*/$1/
            or warn "Unable to fix column at line $.";
    }

    print $outfh join("\t", @columns), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. The code you have corrected still seems to have a bug, line 15 is replaced with all "1".

Answer (score 0):

You need to define scope for your variables with 'my' in declaration itself when you use 'use strict'. 
In your case, you should use my @sort = sort {....} in first line and
you should have an array reference $t defined somewhere to de-reference it in second line. You don't have @array declared anywhere in this code, that is the reason you got all those errors. Make sure you understand what you are doing before you do it.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate the help.  I avoided using @array altogether and just stuck with splitting and sorting the lines by column.  I also realised since my input is strings instead of numeral, I should have used the cmp instead of <=>.